# Remove dependency of a git project from other existing projects

Tags: git, clone, project

During a C++ project (project A), Unfortunately I cloned a previous project (project B) inside the ongoing project (project A). Now any commit I make inside the project A changes the original cloned project repository (project B).  My question is how I can remove this dependency? I mean I am interested to only use a copy of Project B inside Project A without any link between these two projects.

Thank You

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand how a Git "commit" or "push" from one project could affect a completely different project.  Could you please clarify?  Suggestion: have you considered doing a `git init` and simply copying your current source to a brand new repository?

Comment: Sorry If my question is vague.
As I understood, since I cloned an old project inside the New one. Any changes i make in the codes related to the old project (inside the new project), causes changes in the old project when I push my new project. My aim was to only use a copy of the old project not linking these two project together.

Answer (score 3):

In the root of your cloned folder you can find a ".git" folder that holds the repository information. Delete that folder to remove git references.